# How can I fix hardhat deploy Error `no matching function` for `deployed()`?

Tags: solidity, ethers.js, hardhat-deploy

When I use Hardhat to deploy the contract in Sepolia, I keep getting the following error:

[image]

My deploy script:

```
const { ethers } = require("hardhat");

async function main() {
  const whitelistContract = await ethers.getContractFactory("Whitelist");
  const deployedWhitelistContract = await whitelistContract.deploy(10);
  await deployedWhitelistContract.deployed();
  console.log("Whitelist Contract Address:", deployedWhitelistContract.address);
}

main()
  .then(() => process.exit(0))
  .catch((error) => {
    console.error(error);
    process.exit(1);
  });
```

My hardhat-config file:

```
require("@nomicfoundation/hardhat-toolbox");
require("dotenv").config({ path: ".env" });

const QUICKNODE_HTTP_URL = process.env.QUICKNODE_HTTP_URL;
const PRIVATE_KEY = process.env.PRIVATE_KEY;

module.exports = {
  solidity: "0.8.10",
  networks: {
    hardhat: {},
    sepolia: {
      url: QUICKNODE_HTTP_URL,
      accounts: [`0x${PRIVATE_KEY}`],
   },
  },
};
```

Answer (score 1):

The error message shows, `.deployed()` does not exist. so use `waitForDeployment()` instead `.deployed()`.

and also use `.target` or `await deployedWhitelistContract.getAddress()` instead of `.address`

RIGHT CODE:

```
const { ethers } = require("hardhat");

async function main() {
  const whitelistContract = await ethers.getContractFactory("Whitelist");
  const deployedWhitelistContract = await whitelistContract.deploy(10);
  await deployedWhitelistContract.waitForDeployment();
  console.log("Whitelist Contract Address:", await deployedWhitelistContract.getAddress());
}

main()
  .then(() => process.exit(0))
  .catch((error) => {
    console.error(error);
    process.exit(1);
  });
```

Answer (score 0):

Remove 0x from the private key.
Just pass the private key like this

```
accounts: [process.env.PRIVATE_KEY]
```

Comment: I deployed without 0x and happened the same error: "TypeError: no matching function"

Comment: This is true **if** the private key already has the `0x` prefix in the .env file

Comment: @RohanNero Not in my case, I've never prefixed it with `0x`, neither in the .env nor in the config. Not sure what's the case LOL

Answer (score 0):

Hardhat-tools changed the deployment's function syntax. For hardhat-tools 3.0.0 `deploy()` is now `deployContract()` and `deployed()` is now `awaitForDeployment()`

You can either downgrade your hardhat-tools version or use the new syntax.

Comment: This answer was taken **directly from the OP's question body** to better fit the Q and A format